# How to get local UTC time Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

You need to translate the time (UTC + 7) into the time that the user has on the phone.
My code:

```
String date = '20211231031500';
var dateTime = DateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").parse(date, true);
dateLocal = dateTime.toLocal();
```

Error: `Trying to read MM from 20211231031500 at position 14`

Comment: `parse` cannot do this because it will try to consume the whole string as the `yyyy` part (not just the first 4 digits). You will need to break the string into substrings of length 4, 2, 2, 2, etc and parse each individually, then use the `DateTime.utc` constructor. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/DateTime.utc.html